# Electron: require() of ES Module

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm trying to make a simple app for the first time, However I keep getting this error whenever I try to import any npm package. I'm unsure of what I did wrong because I'm using the npm package `electron-reload` and that's not throwing any errors.

`ERROR:`
[require() of ES Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgdyP.png)

This is my `tsconfig.json:`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",                                 
    "module": "CommonJS",                              
    "outDir": "./app/js/",                                   
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true,                                
  },
  "exclude": ["./app/js/**/*.js"],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

This is the code in which the error is being thrown:

```
import Hwid from "hwid";

ipcMain.on("get-hwid", (event) => {
    console.log(Hwid());
});
```

And lastly, this is my `BroswerWindow` code:

```
const window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 700,
        frame: false,
        height: 700,
        resizable: false,
        transparent: true,
        roundedCorners: true,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, "../design/imgs/dully_logo.png"),
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
            devTools: false,
        },
    });
    window.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../design/index.html"));
```

I'm using TypeScript because I prefer it more than regular JS, I'm just stuck on what to do or why this error stops my development. I'm expecting the package to run like normal, yet nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Put an entry index.**cjs** with the code `import('./index.js')` and in package.json you can already add `"type": "module"`.

Comment: This is not recommended for Electron’s main entry point due to possible race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

`hwid` is an [ESM module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) and your `tsconfig.json` specifies to write modules using CommonJS, which is the `require()` function. `tsc` (or other compilers) converts your `import` statements to `require()` calls, which is not permitted with ESM (as the error says). Either use an older version of `hwid` which may support ESM or change `module` to `'es2020'` and set `moduleResolution` to `'node'`.

Comment: Yeah but now, I get: `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: @fxncis You also need to properly migrate your project to ESM, you need to add `"type": "module"` to package.json or rename all your files to have a `.mjs` extension. Some modules will break. Dynamic require()s will need to become async dynamic import()s, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but now those don't even help. I'm still directing the same error, and I think it's mainly because electron doesn't allow ES6 functions.

Comment: @fxncis Try installing the `esm` module and running your app with `-r esm`. (e.g. `node -r esm .`

Comment: Okay, now for some reason I'm getting this error? https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/942646229110759444/964232204521713745/unknown.png

Comment: @static [Support for ES Modules in Electron will land in Electron 28 and will be available in the electron-nightly released on August 31st](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21457)

Comment: oh finally will we have ES modules on Electron and we can use native node api without messing around with build configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `const Hwid = require('hwid')`

Comment: You can't use require() in TypeScript.

Comment: @0xLogN Stop to disinform. I am work with legacy code on JS and writing code on TS. For importing JS files to TS I need to use require instead of import.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that your bundler (Webpack, Vite, etc.) works correctly, or start using one if you aren’t already.

#### Further reading

- [This comment](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21457#issuecomment-1099904505) on Electron issue #21457