# pdf.js lib inside Electron main process

Tags: electron, pdf.js

I'm trying to make pdf.js lib work inside my main Electron process.

```
import { getDocument } = require('pdfjs-dist');
```

Upon startup I am getting the following error:

```
require() of ES Module C:\Workspaces\Workspaces\Stellifill\electron\stellifill\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.mjs not supported. Instead change the require of C:\Workspaces\Workspaces\Stellifill\electron\stellifill\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

I've tried to change the `nodeIntegration` parameter to `true`, but this didn't work.

Tried the `index.cjs` and switching package.json `type` to `module` to no avail. Other types of errors came up.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Because you mentionned it, `nodeIntegration` is for renderer process only, and enabling it is a [security risk](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron: require() of ES Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865552/electron-require-of-es-module)

Comment: Indeed, I figured that wouldn't help me. I tried everything mentioned in that other question to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed by using `pdfjs-dist@3.4.120` instead of `pdsjs-dist@4.0.189` but original cause remains unknown as my Electron app is using import style statements.

Answer (score 0):

The latest pdf.js ship with esm module.

which bundler do you use? You can't conbine require with esm module based on the error message.